# Aws adding Network Interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am using centos 7 AMI.
I add new network interface to this system, called eth1 with the following settings:

```
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
USERCTL="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6INIT="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT="1"
```

I assign the EIP for public connections.
I try to ping from eth0 to eth1, and it works.

Looks like this is internal connection but there is no public connections at all.
I also open all ports for public usage

but there is no incoming from public ip at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have associated EIP and all the VPC configurations are prefect as suggested as best practices.

Other things you need to check is if you have changed `source destination check`

**You will find option for same from EC2 launch windows :**

[image]
I hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: i did it, but the same problem

Comment: There are things you should check such as :
1. Your subnet has a route table.
2. You've attached an internet gateway to your vpc
3. check if you have disabled change source/dest check
4. check access list option to make sure you have proper inbound and outbound rules for the same subnet.

Comment: 1. the subnet has route table..2. there is internet on this devce. 3.disabled.4. acl is open to everywhere